# Android Motion Event Hold Down Button

Tags: android

I have a seemingly simple question that I need help with. I have a button. I want it so when I click on the button quickly it adds one to a total. I also want it to be so that when I hold down this same button for about 2 seconds, it removes one from the total. The only part I am having trouble with is the motion event part. I have been experimenting with ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN with no luck. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
switch (event.getAction())
       {    
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           {
               total ++;
               return true;
           }

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           {
               if(total >0){
                total--;
               }
               return true;
           }
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the Button's [`setOnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) and [`setOnLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29)?

The only limitation with this approach is that you cannot set the the timeout value, which is somewhat over 1,5 seconds, if I remember correctly.

If you're persistent about the two seconds (or some other value), then I suppose you could use an onTouchListener and keep track of the pressed time yourself. In that case, the MotionEvent's [`getDownTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getDownTime%28%29) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works perfect. I did not know you could add more than one action listeners to a button!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please consider accepting my response as the answer to your question, as that will help out others running into a similar problem. :)